# Как вычислить среднее значение элементов ArrayList c помощью Java 8 streams

Tags: java

Как правильно записать выражение с использованием Stream?

В части `array.stream().average()` (в конце кода) IDE подчеркивает `average()`:

> cannot resolve symbol

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number of elements in the array:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array.add((int)(Math.random() * 10));
    }
    Stream<Integer> stream = array.stream();
    double average = array.stream().average();
    System.out.print(average);
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(array).average();` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский неа. Во-первых, `array` - это список (хоть и со странным названием), так что `Arrays.stream()` для него не подойдёт. Во-вторых, всё равно для использования метода `average` нужно приводить поток к `IntStream`.

Comment: @Regent угу. увидел ужО

Answer (score 4):

Для использования метода [average](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--) нужно `Stream<Integer>` привести к `IntStream`:

```
OptionalDouble average = array.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).average();
if (average.isPresent())
{
    System.out.print(average.getAsDouble());
}
```

И называть список (*list*) массивом (*array*) - плохая идея: можно запросто подумать, что `array` - это `Integer[]`, а не `List<Integer>`.